# Fragment Switch Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a problem with fragment switch. In my application the user to complete a task to go through 3 fragment. Specifically, I have a structure like this:

**[F1] --> [F2] --> [F3]**

I am using a navigation drawer and F1 is instantiated as the user clicks on an item in the drawer.
However when the insertion of data has been completed (this means that it is in the F3) the user must click a button (it will launch an AsyncTask because data must be stored in a database) that redirects it to F1 and must be populated a listView with the data that it has included in the previous Fragment (F2 and F3).
Now the problem is: How can I move between F3 and the F1 and populate the list of F1? I know that this operation must be done in "onPostExecute" method of AsyncTask, but i don't understand how recover the listView and populate it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use callbacks to pass a strign from F3 to F1. seperate each value with a comma so you have a CSV string.

String [] seperatedList = passedStr.split(",");

builds an array from this string then set this array as the adapters data and call

listview.setadapter(adapter);

Sorry these replies come late, I have been busy. This is one way to pass Strings between.

```
    String csv = "value0,value1,value2,value";
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("YOUR_KEY", csv);
```

Then do your transaction and commit etc. inside your fragments onCreate call:

```
   String csv = getArguments().getString("YOUR_KEY");
   String [] seperatedValues = csv.split(",");
```

This is one way, it may help your if you want more info let me know ill do my best.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to give me an example?

Comment: @Rick91 apologies, would you still need an example?

Comment: If you could yes, it wpuld be very useful for me.

Comment: @Rick91 added one example.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue using this way:
You are using NavigationDrawer. So you have an Activity and your activity layout has a FrameLayout like this

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In `@+id/frame_container`you are populating your Fragments like F1,F2... Fn.
You can populating fragment in your frameContainer using this way:

```
Fragment fragment=new F1();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

In your Fragment F1's after onCreateView() you can check is data available in your database that have to show in ListView.If data available then show it in listView using an Adapter.
Now , When You are you in Fragment F3 , after successfully saving data on database, you can instantiate Fragment F1 using previous code.
Navigation Drawer [Example is Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/).
Use ListView Adapter [Example Here](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html).
Thanks and sorry for bad English.